# DrRacket loading file error

Tags: lisp, racket

when I use load procedure to load an existing file,

```
(load "coins.rkt")
```

the Racket pop up an error:

```
coins.rkt:1:0: #%top-interaction: unbound identifier;
 also, no #%app syntax transformer is bound in: #%top-interaction
```

I'm not sure what's wrong.

My Racket version is 6.2.1 on MacOS 10.10.3.

Comment: The error is obviously in the content of the file, but if you don't post it, how  can we help you?

Comment: Why would you use `load` in Dr Racket? Use the menu (File->Open). On the command line, use `enter!`

Comment: What's in your first line of that file? `#lang racket` ?